# Windows PDF printer driver with commenting enabled

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

Is there a PDF printer driver that allows PDFs to be created with commenting and markups enabled? I want users with Acrobat Reader to be able to use the markup the PDF files (like using the "Typewriter" function).

I've tried doPDF and PrimoPDF, both of which can create the PDF file but there are not options to enable document commenting so that the Typewriter toolbar shows up in Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Adobe products can enable these features in Adobe Reader. Currently these 2 products can enable usage rights:

- Adobe Acrobat - for less that 500 users
- Adobe LiveCycle Reader Extensions - more than 500 users

More information on Adobe Reader Extensions can be found here:

- [Reader Extensions: Under the hood](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=Reader_Extensions_-_Under_the_hood&gid=8240)
- [Adobe Reader Extensions / Usage Rights](http://www.debenu.com/kb/adobe-reader-extensions-usage-rights/)

Comment: Darn! Any other way to "mark up" or "typewriter fill out" a PDF?